# How to internationalize components with Storybook? i18n with Storybook

Tags: localization, internationalization, storybook, i18next, react-i18next

Trying to link Storybook and i18n, but Storybook doesn't recognize the keys.
I've configured the files as instructed.
The translation files are stored in the public/en/app.json folder.
Errors in the console. - request.js:44     GET http://localhost:6006/locales/en/app.json 404 (Not Found) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czebc.png)

*config/storybook/preview.tsx*

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import type { Preview } from '@storybook/react';

import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from '../../src/shared/config/i18n/i18n';

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },

  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <Suspense fallback="">
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
          <Story />
        </I18nextProvider>
      </Suspense>
    ),
  ],
};

export default preview;
```

*src/shared/config/i18n/i18n.ts*

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: false,
    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },

    react: { useSuspense: false },

    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },

  });

export default i18n;
```

*EXAMPLE (component for storybook with i18n - hook useTranslate)*

```
......

import { AppLink } from 'shared/ui/AppLink';

export const Sidebar: FC = () => {
  const { t, ready } = useTranslation('app');

  if (!ready) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
          <AppLink to="/">
            <span>{t('sidebar.link.home')}</span>
          </AppLink>

          <AppLink to="/about">
            <span>{t('sidebar.link.about')}</span>
          </AppLink>
    </div>
  );
};
```

"Please see the files attached above